# How do I fetch displayed time when user clicks submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which displays present time. User clicks submit button and the exact present time should get saved in mysql table.
But I cant figure out how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
p{font-family:Verdana;}
</style>
<body>

<p>The Current time is:</p>
<p id="example"></p>

<script>
var display=setInterval(function(){Time()},0);

function Time()
{
var date=new Date();
var time=date.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=time;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Lets the user clicks "SUBMIT" button at time 8:02:43 PM, then this time should get stored in mysql table called `time`

Comment: You have to have a back-end server interact with the database. So, you'd usually have an API call from the front-end to request that the back-end update the database.

Comment: Either do a manual POST event to the server or create a form with a hidden input element that also contains the datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a server, for example, [Grails](https://grails.org/) or any other web server and have an controller endpoint over there. Then you can save it to MySQL database using Grails repository